# Creating an array of timestamps between two timestamps in pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have two timestamp columns in my pyspark dataframe. I want to create a third column which has the array of timestamp hours between the two timestamps.

[image]

This is the code I wrote for that..

```
# Creating udf function
def getBetweenStamps(st_date, dc_date):
    import numpy as np
    hr = 0
    date_list = []
    runnig_date = st_date
    while (dc_date>runnig_date):
        runnig_date = st_date+timedelta(hours=hr)
        date_list.append(runnig_date)
        hr+=1
    dates = np.array(date_list)
    return dates
udf_betweens = F.udf(getBetweenStamps, ArrayType(DateType()))

# Using udf function
orders.withColumn('date_array', udf_betweens(F.col('start_date'), F.col('ICUDischargeDate'))).show()
```

However this is showing the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I think the inputs to the functions are going in as two arrays and not as two datetimes causing the error. Is there any way around this? Any other way of solving this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error when returning numpy array from your udf. You can simply return the `date_list` and it will work.

```
def getBetweenStamps(st_date, dc_date):
    import numpy as np
    hr = 0
    date_list = []
    runnig_date = st_date
    while (dc_date>runnig_date):
        runnig_date = st_date+timedelta(hours=hr)
        date_list.append(runnig_date)
        hr+=1
    return date_list
udf_betweens = F.udf(getBetweenStamps, ArrayType(DateType()))
```

To test the above function:

```
df = spark.sql("select current_timestamp() as t1").withColumn("t2", col("t1") + expr("INTERVAL 1 DAYS"))
df.withColumn('date_array', udf_betweens(F.col('t1'), F.col('t2'))).show()
```